# Is this the right way to enable power saving with Bumblebee?

Tags: bumblebee, gpu

I am dual booting. Win7 for the occasional game, and Ubuntu 12.10 for everything else.

I've got a Nvidia 680m 4GB GPU. At https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

If I only want to install bumblebee for its power savings feature. Is it enough just to run:

```
`sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends bumblebee linux-headers-generic`
```

Or should I install the proprietary drivers from Nvidia, via:

```
`sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic`.
```

Is there any difference for power saving between the two drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in the way power management is handled. Either way, `bbswitch` will be used by default. When installing `bumblebee-nvidia` too, you will just have a bunch of extra files which slows done kernel updates. If you do not need it, do not install it.

(kernel updates will be slown down because the nvidia kernel module needs to be built.)